# gradle:compileGroovy flutter errors ,

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, groovy

I have tried to install new version of gradle and change the windows display language. The problem haven't been solved.

I tried to solve error using this same issue with the link
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/134241#issue-1886464396

But it didn't work.

I tried to install again android studio and update plugins . But no result have earned.